SSL Error: ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR - only happening with Chrome -- all other browsers fine
I get the following error in Chrome:
ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR when trying to connect to a client website.
This only happens in Chrome and for everyone.
The "website" is hosted in IIS and is just a web.config with a redirect to a site hosted elsewhere.
The certificate is installed into a custom certificate store (just a folder on another drive) which is mirrored on a second server. The IIS binding is correct, the HTTPS certificate is set to pull from the certificate store. The two web servers are mirroring correctly. This is a normal setup for many of our website for our client.
Originally I thought this problem was due to a missing SAN (the non www. domain) and asked the client to reissue the certificate with the added SAN hoping it'd fix.
Upon installation of the newly reissued certificate (with new valid from/to dates), I noticed that different SSL checkers would report the old certificate sometimes. Looking just now with FF dev tools, I can the non www. domain returning an the old certificate, where the www. domain returns the new certificate.
I am assuming Chrome detects this weirdness and just bottoms out, whereas the other browsers are happy, but it could be a red herring.
What's weird is, I purged the server of all the old certificates so I've no idea how they're being returned. The hosting provider is convinced it's not the load balancer.
Anyone have any idea?

Which SSL checkers have you used. Have you tried ssllabs.com which also shows if you have different setups for IPv4 and IPv6. Its not uncommon that they are setup differently and only one is broken.

ssllabs.com actually returns the same cert for both www.mysite.com and mysite.com. Some of the others such as https://www.sslshopper.com/r returns different, but that might be caching results, Firefox has the same behaviour (but is happy with the cert and loads). Still no go with Chrome. It could be something else with the cert Chrome doens't like but every checker appears to be happy with it.

Hard to tell. If you could publish the URL one could have a closer look. Have you've tried from different networks? Are you maybe behind some DPI firewall? Or does it happen for every user of Chrome, no matter from which network?
